# Unable to delete gcloud composer environment

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to delete gcloud environments. One did not successfully create (no associated Airflow or Bucket) and one did. When I attempt to delete, I get an error message (after a really long time) of `RPC Skipped due to required preoperation not finished yet.` The logs don't provide any valuable information, and I wasn't able to find anything wrong in the cluster. The only solution I have found so far is to delete the entire project, but I would prefer not to. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below to delete the environment's resources manually:

- Delete GKE cluster that corresponds to the environment
- Delete the Google Storage bucket used by the environment
- [Delete the related deployment](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/deleting-deployments) with:
  `gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> --delete-policy=ABANDON`
- Then try again to delete the Composer environment with:
  `gcloud composer environments delete <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location <LOCATION>`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Something I wanted to tack on is a lot more detail is provided in Activity Logs for a project (not just environment logs).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share what worked for me in case someone else runs into this problem as I followed all the steps above and still could not delete the composer environment.

My 'gcloud composer environments list' command was returning '0', but I could see my environment was still in the console view and when I tried to delete it, I would get the same error message as honlicious. Additionally, I ran 'gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding' to try to give my Compute Engine ServiceAccount the composer.serviceAgent role, but this still did not resolve my issue. What eventually worked was disabling the Cloud Composer API and then re-enabling it. This removed my old environment I was unable to previously delete.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when I tried to create and delete Cloud Composer by Terraform.
I created a Service Account apart from the Composer and this led to deletion it in the first order during a terraform destroy operation.

So the correct order is:

1. Delete Composer environment
2. Delete Composer’s Service Account