# Unable to delete GCP Cloud Composer environment

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I have to disable the composer, and cloud data fusion APIs and enable them back so i get the default service accounts recreated. There is a problem with data fusion service account which i'm unable to recover from.
When removing the environments, i'm unable to delete Composer Environment. I dont get past this error message:

Error Message:

```
DELETE operation on this environment failed 2 minutes ago with the following error message:
RPC Skipped due to required preoperation not finished yet.
```

What i have tried is : [Cloud Composer is not getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927673/cloud-composer-is-not-getting-deleted)

Any help on this please?

Comment: So you have tried the `gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete` with the `--delete-policy=ABANDON` flag? Followed by the command to delete your environment ? If yes, have you checked your service account permissions to delete the environment? Your service account should have **composer.environments.delete** to be able to delete it.

Comment: I tried with policy=ABANDON flag.
From cli, i get the object is not found. I tried giving the name of the composer, GKE Cluster Name.
I gave admin role for the service account too. 
In all cases i'm getting object is not found on the cli. 
`gcloud deployment-manager deployments delete _______  --delete-policy=ABANDON`

When i tried to delete the composer environment, as well i get No such environment found. 
`gcloud composer environments delete _______  --location asia-northeast1`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me finally was to disable the composer API and enable it back. Then try to delete the composer environment. Thanks to [Unable to delete gcloud composer environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363210/unable-to-delete-gcloud-composer-environment)